# Package Creation fails due to components in an unrelated package

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, unmanaged-package, packaging-2

I'm trying to set up a package and when creating, I get errors related to code from the default directory (not the one I'm trying to create the package for).

Structure could be (simplified, the structure is SFDX compliant)

- src

  - defaultdir

    - someunneededfile
    - otherunneededfile
  - packagedir

    - importantfile
    - otherimportantfile

All code from packageddir is deploying to a scratch org, but when creating a package files from defaultdir are coming up as errors (they don't deploy to scrtch orgs, various reasons)

my sfdx-project.json

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "src/packagedir",
      "package": "packagedir",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "default": false,
      "versionDescription": "",
      "dependencies": [],
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "definitionFile": "config/shapeRepresentation.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "src/defaultdir",
      "package": "defaultdir",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "default": true,
      "versionDescription": "",
      "dependencies": [],
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "definitionFile": "config/shapeRepresentation.json"
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "58.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "packagedir": "0Ho0900000Packaged",
    "defaultdir": "0Ho09000001OTHERID"
  }
}
```

command is

```
sf package version create  -v privateDevHub --path src/packagedir --installation-key mykeyhere
```

I honestly don't understand what could be driving it, given it aligns with docs. Any ideas?